# GeoServer and local PostgreSQL database without Internet

Tags: postgresql, geoserver, pgadmin

simple question: can I work on GeoServer and local PostgreSQL database on my PC without need for Internet connection ?

would I be able to connect GeoServer to the database and create layers ? also would I be able to use pgAdmin and postGIS full usage ?

Comment: I can't see why not - unless geoserver downloads maps or some such. Certainly pgadmin and postgis will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

> simple question: can I work on GeoServer and local PostgreSQL database on my PC without need for Internet connection ?

Yes

> would I be able to connect GeoServer to the database and create layers ?

Yes

> also would I be able to use pgAdmin and postGIS full usage ?

Yes